# Meta Source Control?

Tags: svn, version-control

What do source control developers use for source control?

Is the source for subversion stored in a subversion repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer to that is an unequivocal "yes". For example:

- [Subversion source code](http://svn.collab.net/viewvc/svn/trunk/)
- [Git source code](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=summary)
- [Mercurial source code](http://selenic.com/repo/hg)

Comment: There was some celebration going on on the Subversion website when they moved the project off CVS.

Answer (score 3):

If they are not eating their own dog food, *nobody* is going to use their stuff!